# Creating a ggplot in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

I tried to create a ggplot based on this data:

[image]

Sorry, but i can't provide more from the data.

I got this from an output of effect from the effects package.

Now i want to draw a ggplot that combines the probabilities from prob.X1 to prob.X6. It should look like this:

[image]

That's what i already tried:

```
Eff.1 <- Effect(focal.predictors = "AvRating", mod= V6)
Eff.df <- data.frame((Eff.1))
```

This code provides the chart from the top.

With this i tried to get the ggplot:

```
ggplot(Eff.df) + geom_area(aes(x=AvRating, y=prob.X1))
```

But this creates just the plot out of the first and the second column.

I tried to add more geoms like this (that doesn't work):

```
ggplot(Eff.df) + geom_area(aes(x=AvRating, y=prob.X1)) + geom_area(aes(x=AvRating, y=prob.X2))
```

Than i tried to connect the columns and plot this(that doesn't work):

```
Eff.dfx <- as.numeric((rbind(Eff.df$prob.X1,Eff.df$prob.X2, Eff.df$prob.X3, Eff.df$prob.X4,Eff.df$prob.X5,Eff.df$prob.X6)))
Eff.dfAv <- as.numeric(rep(Eff.df$AvRating,6))
ggplot(Eff.df) + geom_area(aes(x=Eff.dfAv, y= Eff.dfx))
```

Would you help me with the code of this ggplot?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: please provide the data you are using. `dput()` should help you with that. Also provide some code you have already tried. Edit both to your question.

Comment: probably you can first have a look @ [the SO documentation on ggplot2](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/1334/ggplot2#t=201608241415466235163) or the [R Graphics Cookbook](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/)

Comment: ah. Thanks a lot. This link helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It always helps if you actually provide a MWE or data that people can use to actually help you. Since you didn't, here is some data already in the format that you probably need. You will need `reshape2::melt` to convert your data (which is currently a picture, which can't have been easier than posting data) to the proper format.

You probably shouldn't use connections between the ratings, since that implies that you have information about values halfway between them

```
library(dplyr)

usableData <-
  data.frame(
    avgRating = factor(rep(0:5, each = 6))
    , value = factor(rep(1:6, 6))
    , count = rnorm(36, rep(seq(300,40, length.out = 6)), 10)
  ) %>%
  group_by(avgRating) %>%
  mutate(prob = count / sum(count))


ggplot(usableData
       , aes(x = avgRating
             , y = prob
             , fill = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_fill_brewer(direction = -1)
```

[image]

If you really, really have a good reason for using the connected lines, you should be able to do something like this:

```
usableData %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(avgRating) %>%
  mutate(cumsum = cumsum(count)
         , cumProb = cumsum / sum(count)
         , cumProbPre = c(0,cumsum[-length(cumsum)]) / sum(count)
         ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = as.numeric(avgRating)
             , ymin = cumProbPre
             , ymax = cumProb
             , fill = value
             )) +
  geom_ribbon() +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_fill_brewer(direction = -1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this answer. You really helped me.
Sorry for this useless picture. I was doing this the first time and wasn't aware of how to insert the data so you can use them.